# High Volume MongoDB with Twitter Streaming API, Ruby on Rails, Heroku setup

Tags: mongodb, twitter, heroku, streaming

I'm looking to re-code an application to better handle spikes in tweets. I'm moving to Heroku and MongoDB (either MongoLab or MongoHQ) for the database solution.

During certain news events, tweet volume might spike to 15,000 / second. Typically with each tweet, I parse the tweet and store various pieces of data such as user data, etc. My idea is to store the raw tweets in a separate collection, and have a separate process grab raw tweets and parse them. The goal here is when there is a massive spike in tweets, my application isn't trying to parse all of these, but is essentially backlogging the raw tweets in another collection. As the volume slows, the process can take care of the backlog over time.

My question is three fold:

1. Can MongoDB handle this type of volume with regards to inserts into a collection at a rate of 15,000 tweets per second?
2. Any idea on the better setup: MongoHQ or MongoLab?
3. Any feedback on the overall setup?

Thanks!

Comment: A bit late on this one, but a [recent blog post](http://blog.hartleybrody.com/asynchronous/) explains how a *log now, process later* method works using RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The write volume that it will handle depends on lots of factors - hardware, indexes, size of each document, etc. Your best bet is to test it in the environment you're planning to use. If the demands of the write load exceed the capacity of a single mongo server, you can always use just multiple shards.
2. They are very similar, but there are some differences in pricing and the actual site design has a bunch of differences. There's a thread of discussion about it here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20782/mongodb-hosting-mongolab-vs-mongohq-vs-mongomachine
3. Overall it seems to make sense. Sounds like you will probably want to flesh out some details about how you will be processing the backlog. Will you be polling it by querying periodically, deleting tweets from the backlog as it processes them, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Completely agree on the need to test this. In general, mongo can handle that many writes, but in practice it depends on the size of your set up, other operations, indexes, etc.

I had to do a similar approach for collecting tons of metrics data. I used a lightweight event-machine process to accept incoming requests in parallel, and store them in a simple format, then another process would take those requests and send them up to a central server. The main goal was to make sure no data was lost if the central server was down, but it also allowed me to put in some throttling logic so that the spikes in data wouldn't overwhelm the system.

I'd be interested to see how this works out for you price-wise, vs. a vps like linode. (I'm a huge Heroku fan, but with certain architectures it can get pricey quickly)